# pybedtools: ImportError: cannot import name scripts

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to import Pybedtools in Spyder.

```
from pybedtools import BedTool
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

 File "<ipython-input-13-7a8ea5d1dea8>", line 1, in <module>
 from pybedtools import BedTool

 File "/Users/michaelsmith/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pybedtools/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
 from . import scripts

ImportError: cannot import name scripts
```

I just downloaded Anaconda and there doesn't seem to be a reason as to why this happens. What is the typical protocol for resolving bugs like this?

UPDATE:

So within my pybedtools folder there is a `scripts` folder (which is presumably the module we're trying to import). I changed both the command within `__init__.py` to:

```
from . import scripts2
```

and changed the name of the folder to `scripts2` as well. However, I still get the error as such:

```
ImportError: cannot import name scripts2
```

So I must be doing something wrong here, which module should I be renaming exactly? Sorry if this is a silly question, I am quite new to python.

Answer (score 2):

This is caused because Anaconda has a module named `scripts` and therefore your import is "shadowed" by that module. You can double check that when you call `import scripts` in a new notebook it works even if you have never defined such a module. A very good explanation of import traps can be found here:

http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html

A workaround would be to rename the `script` module of `pybedtools` to something else and also change all the imports to the new name.

Comment: Thank you! So I renamed the `scripts` folder of `pybedtools` to `scripts2`, and I am still getting an import error. Maybe I misunderstood your advice?

Comment: I guess you need to look also at the code where `import scripts` is used and change it to `import scripts2`